# TexStudio Slow Typing

Tags: texstudio

I am using the version TeXstudio 2.12.16 (git 2.12.16). When I type it takes a considerable amount of time before the words actually appear on the screen. It seems like TexStudio is giving me a lot of suggestions in the middle of a word, that it cannot keep up with the writing. Any ideas on how to fix this?

(I am new to both LaTeX and TexStudio so this may have something to do with it too)

Thanks a lot for any help

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: This is not a question related to LaTex, but about the TexStudio editor. You should consider take your question to another place, and maybe provide a little more information in the process: OS? TexStudio version? PC specs? Options?

Comment: Texstudio does have some autocompletion of commands at least, which can be turned off I think under Options -> Configure TeXstudio -> Completion. Does this happen for normal text, or commands, or both? Have you tried simply reinstalling TeXstudio? (@SalatielGarcia: Questions about (La)TeX specific editors aren't  necessarily off topic I'd say.)

Comment: It was only happening for commands, and yes I have tried reinstalling and even downgrading TeXstudio, neither of which helped. I played around with the completion settings and it seems that the problem was caused by ToolTip-Preview and ToolTip-Help being turned on. After I turned them off the problem disappeared. Thank you @TorbjørnT.

Answer (score 4):

Something that worked for me was to deselect Inline Checking. It is in Options/Configure/Editor. It seems that checking for syntax, especially, slows down the program. Deselecting inline checking removes the bold of some words, but still maintains different colors for `\begin`, `\usepackage`, and other keywords. And it makes the program faster.